# Github Manual Merge Commit Results in Adding All Files Already Pulled to the Commit

Tags: git, merge

I have problems to understand what git is doing when I manually merge a multi person repository.

The following is what I am doing:

1. I commit all my changes in multiple commits
2. I pull the complete repository ('git pull')
3. I manually solve all merge conflicts (in this case two files/classes)
4. I use 'git add .' to compose the commit
5. I use 'git status' to check before committing

On point five is where I struggle. The status reveals that git wants to commit about 200 files rather than the three merged files. The commit is composed of all files that have changed during the last pull and the pull starting the merging.

The bottom line is Git wants to recommit everything changed during the merge including already committed files that were untouched by either the merge affords or the changes I did.

Since I lack the knowledge if this is ok and a merge commit should really be that extensive, I hard pull everything (catching up with the current master) and copy all my recent changes to the folder (I am the only one committing to the sub project so it is possible).

If anyone can verify that what git is doing on 'git add .' is correct, I would be very happy.

**[Update]**

To clarify what I observed, lets take a look at the following example:

projectA -> Mixed content (Everyone touches it)
projectB -> All about Java (Only I touch it)
projectC -> All about C# (I never touch it)

- I committed my stuff in project B and also changes to two files in project A that lead to the merge conflict.
- I do a pull and get all changes from projects A and C (B had no changes). Two files in A get merged with the normal merge markers (<<<<<< HEAD etc).
- I solve the conflicts with the two files in project A and save it.
- I do a 'git add .'
- Doing 'git status' I see a lot of files in projectC now being green and appear to be part of the upcomming commit.

I think that I see files of project C being part of the upcomming commit (current set of files about to be committed) seams totally wrong. Out of fear I just every time fetch the repository from origin and do a hard reset copying my stuff in project B over the new up to date version.

So basically if I try to merge by hand I get puzzled and afraid and do the merge the other way round (get up to date, copy changes, recommitting changes).

Comment: Can you clarify "recommit everything changed during the merge"? If there was a conflict during the merge it would not be resolved automatically and the other files has not yet been committed. Or I am misunderstanding something in your description.

Comment: I added an update section

Comment: If it is not a fast-forward merge, the merge will become a commit on your local branch. (If there are no merge conflicts, this happens automatically). If other people has changed in "C", their changes will be a part of the merge into your local branch. If you are committing to your local branch (and I think you are if the merged files is a part of the commit), the changed files from other people should be a part of that commit.

Comment: Think of the pull as a commit where you get all the changes that others have made and commit those changes into your branch.

Comment: This is all happening for the same master branch

Comment: note also you should not run `git add .`, because it may cause any yet untracked file to sneak into history. Instead, you should git add only files which were conflicting, after you resolve the conflict.

Comment: Local and remote is not the same. Maybe I don't understand your problem fully. Try to reproduce the problem with a simpler case and post a smaller, concrete example. You'll get more answers that way. Maybe as a new question, as these comments just add a lot of noise. Good luck.